# Automate MFA login across many browsers, Zoom, etc

Tags: applescript, safari, automator, google-chrome

Our instituion requires multi-factor authentication for a variety of services I use with a 24h expiry period.  I am looking for a way of writing a script I can run which will connect to every service I need daily, and authentic to these all at once.

For example, I use three different browsers (Safari, Firefox, Chrome) which each need authentication, Zoom, Microsoft Teams, and One Note.

I am open to better suggestions, but I would be reasonably happy with a way to simply run a script which runs through all of these, allowing me to do all the authentications in one sitting.

There are some discussions about automation (e.g. [Automate workspace setup](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406287/automate-workspace-setup)), but most questions have specific solutions customized for the application (e.g. [How can I automate taking screenshots of 10,000+ pages?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/235584/how-can-i-automate-taking-screenshots-of-10-000-pages)).

I am fine with having to type passwords, etc. multiple times at one point: my main issue is that, during the day, when I need to access one of these services, having to authenticate is a major cognitive shift, which wastes lots of my time.

I don't mind coding, but don't know the best place to hook in or start.  My previous experiences with applescript have not been positive.

Comment: RE: "My previous experiences with applescript have not been positive." --  If that be the case then not sure what other _language_ is going to get you there as easily as **AppleScript** can. I use **AppleScript** every day to preform the type of tasks you've mentioned including fully automated _scripts_ that also do complete logins, e.g. to various **VPN**'s, Network Shares, etc. including retrieving passwords from the **Keychain**. Opening various _applications_ including _window_ arrangements and layouts on the screen, etc.

Comment: The bottom line is just about everything I do that is multi-step repetitive and can be scripted I do so, so I don't have to continually do everything manually.

Comment: @user3439894 It is helpful to know that AppleScript is the way to go.  I thought that they were switching to Swift. The only relevant docs I see are in the documentation archive which directs me to the Developer Documentation page where I can find no tutorials, or current language reference. I suspect my poor experience is related to a lack of good resources for finding: a) a succinct tutorial for experienced programmers, and b) a clear understanding about how find out what APIs each application supports.

Comment: Yes, **Swift** is a newer _language_ however, **Swift** and basic _vanilla_ **AppleScript** are not really comparable and used for very different things. **AppleScript** is certainly on the way out and **Shortcuts** probably will be the replacement for it and **Automator**, however, I will continue to use **AppleScript** for as long as I can. In **Script Editor** press **⇧⌘L** for the **Library**, and from the **Help** _menu_ there is **Show AppleScript Language Guide**. There is a _third-party utility_ named **Script Debugger** and there are many additional resources on the **Internet**.

Comment: If you're using Big Sur (you don't specify) then: https://support.apple.com/guide/script-editor/welcome/mac | A good resource for older AppleScript: https://macosxautomation.com/applescript/firsttutorial/index.html | O'Reilly has a book that used to be on my bookshelf. (Now I remember who I lent it to!) https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/applescript-the-definitive/0596005571/